# Travel itinerary for Japanese visa

Tags: japan, standard-visitor-visas, itineraries

Hey am from Uganda and am planning for a travel in japan on a visitor visa and among the document asked are the travel itinerary and personal tax return .
How best can I prove my travel itinerary when it comes to hotels and flight?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine...

A list of hotels/accommodations with reservation confirmation with dates.

And a list of transportation if you already made some reservation for them (planes tickets in and out of Japan, planes or train tickets inside Japan... )

Comment: It's usually recommended you don't book flights/accom until the visa is locked in.

Comment: @Mark Every decent accom in Japan has free cancellation until the day before check-in, though; some even have it on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not advised to book your flights, hotels etc before getting the visa confirmed.

You can simply provide a list of the expected dates, locations, maybe activities and costs per day (estimated).  The idea is to show you have a rough idea of a plan, and you know how much it might cost, and the tax return will help show you're likely to be able to cover it.

If staying with or visiting friends, list them too, as it shows you've got contacts there too.